# The iOS 8.1 simulator runtime is not available error in Xcode 6.1

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode6

I was using Xcode 6.0.1 till now and things were fine. Then I upgraded to Xcode 6.1 and tried running my application(which has a deployment target of 7.0) in iPhone 6 simulator. But it shows an error message :

> **The iOS 8.1 simulator runtime is not available**. Download the iOS 8.1 simulator runtime from the Downloads section in Xcode's Preferences

I manually deleted the earlier Xcode (6.0.1) and installed 6.1 from a dmg. 
I tried searching across but couldn't find related stuff. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: Screenshot for warning]

Comment: Under Xcode > Preferences > Downloads > Components, they list which simulators you have downloaded.

Comment: I had similar issue and found that if you run app on iPhone 5 and below simulator then it works fine. Use of iPhone 6/6+ generates the warning.

Comment: Similar issue, gone after updating latest security update 2014-005 (or reboot due to this install)

Answer (score 74):

It is a Mac problem, not an Xcode problem.

Logout the user, shutdown, restart or just reboot Mac. Your Xcode simulator will go back to normal.

Comment: I renamed Xcode.app and ran into this. The reboot helped. I (now) believe I read something about this in recent release notes.

Comment: Old Q&A, but I had this issue migrating from Xcode 10.1 to 10.2, and this result popped up first in google when checking for the error message. This worked for me.

Comment: Works like a charm. I didnt even have the version in preferences for which the error was coming. Restarting helped

Comment: Rebooting also solved for me after Xcode 10.2 to 10.2.1 upgrade.

Answer (score 35):

For anyone still facing this issue, this command worked for me:

```
sudo killall -9 com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService
```

Answer (score 8):

Rebooting did not help me.

Installing/Reinstalling Simulators worked!!

Look under (XCode Preferences-> Downloads -> Components)

Answer (score 4):

**Maintain an accurate list of iOS simulators**

When upgrading, you may drag around old simulators no longer available with your current version of Xcode. You can clean these by running this command in **Terminal**:

```
xcrun simctl delete unavailable
```

Quit **Xcode** first just for good measures. From the documentation:

> Delete a device or all unavailable devices.

Comment: `An error was encountered processing the command (domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError, code=159):
Errors encountered while deleting multiple devices.` -- any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Rebooting my computer fixed this exact issue for me. Same error was thrown for both iOS7 and iOS8 simulators. I'm on OS X 10.10 and Xcode 6.1.

Answer (score 0):

Just had this problem with Xcode 8 beta 5. I downloaded ios8 and 9 simulators, but was not able to run my app. I simply deleted derived data and rebooted my computer. It worked for me.