# The iOS 8.2 simulator runtime is not available on Xcode 7

Tags: ios, runtime, ios-simulator, xcode7

Unable to open liblaunch_sim.dylib.  Try reinstalling Xcode or the simulator runtime.
It seems that all iOS simulators below 9 are not available (after updating to Xcode 7 from Xcode 6.4), though Xcode lets me build for it...[image]

Comment: see this link may be helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26846139/the-ios-8-1-simulator-runtime-is-not-available-error-in-xcode-6-1

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik thank you but Unfortunately this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26846139/the-ios-8-1-simulator-runtime-is-not-available-error-in-xcode-6-1 did not help me, thats why I upload my solution... (I should have marked it in my question though)

Comment: see this link also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31056634/how-can-i-run-the-ios-7-1-simulator-in-xcode-7-0-beta-2

Comment: Anbu.Karthik please read carefully the content of the link you just sent. First of all its xcode beta2 and not official release. Second, the answer that was accepted there is that you can not use other simulator however the correct answer is that you can (on the official release). Third, please remove your negative vote out of my question and answer please. Thanks

Comment: bro I am not give negative vote , if you have a doubt I give my login details

Answer (score 1):

[image]You need to open Preferences -> Download -> iOS 8.2 or any other iOS you like

Comment: Thanks for your Answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue in Xcode 8.2. I have quitted the current Xcode and  restart it again. I find all my downloaded simulators in the list.I selected one of them and run the application. App ran properly.