# Failed to find a suitable device for the type IBSimDev

Tags: xcode, xcode10.2

I'm getting the following 2 errors that seem that alternate every time I try to build. I just upgrade my iOS to 12.2 which forced me to upgrade my osx to Mojave 10.14.4 and my xcode to 10.2.

> Failed to find or create execution context for description.
>
> Filed to find a suitable device for the type IBSimDeviceTypeiPad2x in
>   Assets.xcassets

This I have tried:

Cleaning Build Folder (repeatedly)

Closing and restarting Xcode and the simulator

Deleting Derived Data

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56832489/1032372) may help anyone facing a similar problem.

Answer (score 11):

Run this command in the terminal to make sure all simulator process in the background are killed :

```
sudo killall -9 com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService
```

Comment: My MacBook is running 10.15.5. I had been using Xcode 11.5.1, and also had beta 1 of Xcode 12 installed. I upgraded my iPad mini (5th gen) from iPadOS 13.5.1 to 13.6, and upgraded Xcode from 11.5.1 to 11.6. When I went to run a project on the iPad, Xcode gave me that error. Using the "sudo killall" as you suggested fix the problem for me (the next step would have been rebooting). Thanks!

Comment: this fix worked for me as well, thanks! a reboot likely would have done the same thing, but this is much quicker

Answer (score 7):

I had faced the same issue my issue resolved by doing:

- Clean build folder (<kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>)
- Restart your system (Mac)

**Note**: Also missing simulator after updating to  Xcode 10.3 fix by this solution.

Answer (score 5):

Well I don't know how many other people this is going to help out but here was my issue:

I poked around and finally got another error that said that my simulator runtime is not available. What ended up solving it was simply restarting my macbook found from this thread: [The iOS 8.1 simulator runtime is not available error in Xcode 6.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26846139/the-ios-8-1-simulator-runtime-is-not-available-error-in-xcode-6-1)